# Is it acceptable to put a break points in the Django admin site file (admin.py) of my app to debug?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Simply, I need to debug the admin.py file, but it doesn't give me the chance for this, so the error pops up directly without stopping at the break point or going line by line after it. So here I have a problem at line 14 related to the tuples because I have nested tuples without adding a comma after the nested tuple. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOVdU.png)

I tried to render the page of the admin site to implement the method line by line, but the error happens directly

Sorry for this long question .

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the point in function definition (a line with `def` command). It's not executed. Put it just below - it should stop just before executing that line.